# Gstreamer binaries not included in build output directory when application built with vcpkg

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp, vcpkg

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with VCPKG to build a simple test program that opens a OpenCV VideoCapture object with a gstreamer pipeline to a RTSP feed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto path = "rtspsrc location=rtsp://username:password@192.168.0.115 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink";
    auto cap = new cv::VideoCapture(path, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

This is my vcpkg manifest

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg/master/scripts/vcpkg.schema.json",
  "name": "opencvtest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": [
        {
            "name": "opencv",
            "default-features": true,
            "features": [ "gstreamer" ]
        },
        {
            "name": "gstreamer",
            "default-features": true,
            "features": [ "plugins-good","plugins-base","plugins-ugly","x264" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can build the program just fine but when run, it complains about not finding the rtspsrc element.

```
[ WARN:0@0.014] global H:\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.5.5-923325adf5.clean\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (1127) cv::GStreamerCapture::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: no element "rtspsrc"
[ WARN:0@0.014] global H:\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.5.5-923325adf5.clean\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) cv::GStreamerCapture::isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

This seems reasonable since the build output directory doesn't seem to have all the seemingly necessary gstreamer dll's present, such as gstrtsp*.dll.

How can I get vcpkg to include all the necessary gstreamer dlls into my build output directory? What is the correct way to use OpenCV/gstreamer with vcpkg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vcpkg port of gstreamer does not build the rtsp plugin (which includes the rtspsrc element) by default.
You will need to edit the `portfile.cmake`.

Doing this in a production environment requires you to create your own vcpkg repository, where you can adjust the `portfile.cmake` and thus the build options how ever you want.

If this is something you will need to do I can describe this in more detail.

Short version:
add `-Dgst-plugins-good:rtsp=enabled` to the `vcpkg_configure_meson` build step described in the `portfile.cmake` of gstreamer.